# Changing color of nonselected cell in CellEndEdit isn't sticking

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview with a value entered. If the value of the cell I'm changing is x, and the value of another cell in the dgv is y. If x>y, I want cell1 to be green and cell2 to be black, if equal, both orange. Simple enough. I am determining these values in the CellEndEdit event.

The problem is that the current/selected cell color is changing, but the other cell (cell2) isn't changing. I know this is a paint not firing event or something, but I have tried adding Refresh() after the call, and no good. I have run a break point, and the code is being hit without any problems and the indexes are correct.

Any suggestions? Here's how I'm changing the colors:

```
dgvPoolTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
dgvPoolTable.Rows[indexX].Cells[indexY].Style.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
```

The second line is the one I'm having trouble with.

Should I move this to another event?

Comment: Do you have them backwards?  indexX is usually a column but you are referencing a row, and indexY is usually a row, but you are referencing a column.

Comment: Do you have any treatment that changes the cell (by creating another one for example) ?

Comment: use cellFormat Event

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void dgvPoolTable_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.ColumnIndex == indix your cell1)
        {
            int stutse=1;
            if(e.Value > dgtrans .Rows[e.RowIndex ].Cells [cell2 your index].Value)
             stutse=1;
           else if(e.Value < dgtrans .Rows[e.RowIndex ].Cells [cell2 your index].Value)
            stutse=2;
             else
            stutse=3;
            switch (stutse)
            {
                case 3:

                    e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green;

                    break;
                case 2:
                    e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.GreenYellow;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.LawnGreen;
                    break;

                default:
                    e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.BurlyWood;
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
```